# Получение результат работы модуля ssh2 для NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssh, callback

Что-то мне подсказывает, что необходимо использовать callback для получения результатов работы функции, но не могу понять, как этим методом воспользоваться. Мой код следующий:

```
var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
conn.exec(execomand, function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('Stream closed with code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
        conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(data.toString());
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
});
}).connect({
    host: IPaddress,
    username: loginname,
    password: loginpass,
    port: SSHport
});
```

Как мне обратиться к содержимому data в остальных частях кода?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы просто обратиться достаточно определить переменную в самом начале , например до var conn = new Client(); и потом записать туда данные, если нужна калбек функция то она делается чуть сложнее, хотя я не понимаю зачем она тут нужна, в кратце калбек из ф-ции делается так

```
function myFunc (data, callback) {
тут куча кода, возможно даже асинхронного
callback(returndata)}
```

а вызывать её надо так, например res это объект возврата web сервера

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
myFunc(data, function(err, res_data){
if(data) {
res.end(res_data);
}
if(err) {
var fatalerror = "всё сломалось";
res.end(fatalerror);
}
})
```